# How to call https url using spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-resttemplate

I try to configure restTemplate to call https url in spring boot 3 but that does not compile. For this i use import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts and the code below :

```
fun restTemplate(): RestTemplate {
        val restTemplate = RestTemplate()

        // Load the .p12 file from the test resources directory
        val p12File = ClassPathResource("certs/clientErfin2.p12").file
        val p12Stream = FileInputStream(p12File)

        try {
            // Load the .p12 file into a KeyStore
            val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")
            keyStore.load(p12Stream, "password".toCharArray())

            // Create an SSL context with the KeyStore
            val sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "password".toCharArray())
                    .build()

            // Create an HttpClient with the SSL context
            val httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setSSLContext(sslContext)
                    .build()

            // Create a ClientHttpRequestFactory with the HttpClient
            val requestFactory: ClientHttpRequestFactory = HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient)

            // Set the ClientHttpRequestFactory on the RestTemplate
            restTemplate.requestFactory = requestFactory
        } finally {
            p12Stream.close()
        }

        return restTemplate
    }
```

the line             val requestFactory: ClientHttpRequestFactory = HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient) does not compile because of Cannot access class 'org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencie. How can i fix this?

Thank's!

i tried to add the dependency hc.client5 and that does not resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by adding this to my `gradle.build`

```
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.2.1'
```

and importing this `HttpClientBuilder`:

```
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClientBuilder
```

Answer (score 0):

with combination of spring-boot 3.0.7 and httpclient5 5.2.1, did like following way,

```
         char[] keyStorePasswordAsCharArray = tlsConfig.keyStorePassword().toCharArray();
         char[] keyPasswordAsCharArray = tlsConfig.clientKeyPassword().toCharArray();
         char[] trustStorePasswordAsCharArray = tlsConfig.trustStorePassword().toCharArray();

         try {
            URL keyStoreUrl = ResourceUtils.getURL(tlsConfig.keyStorePath());
            URL trustStoreUrl = ResourceUtils.getURL(tlsConfig.trustStorePath());

            SSLContextBuilder SSLBuilder = SSLContexts.custom();
            SSLBuilder = SSLBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(trustStoreUrl, trustStorePasswordAsCharArray).loadKeyMaterial(keyStoreUrl,
                     keyStorePasswordAsCharArray, keyPasswordAsCharArray);

            SSLContext sslcontext = SSLBuilder.build();
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConSocFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new NoopHostnameVerifier());

            PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManagerBuilder = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
                     .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConSocFactory).build();
            
            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connectionManagerBuilder).build();

            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
            requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

            restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
         } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
         }
```

The code should compile and work.